# removing object from DB, JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

This is my DAO method:

```
public void deleteById(int id){
    TypedQuery<Animal> query = entityManager.createQuery("Select e from Animal e where e.id="+id, Animal.class);
    Animal entity = query.getSingleResult();
    System.out.println(entityManager.contains(entity));
    System.out.println(entity.hashCode());
    entity = entityManager.merge(entity);
    System.out.println("after merge");
    System.out.println(entity.hashCode());
    System.out.println(entityManager.contains(entity));
    entityManager.remove(entity);
}
```

and this is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("{animal}/{name}/{id}/delete")
public String dropAnimal(@PathVariable("id") int id){

    animalDAO.deleteById(id);
    return "glowny";
}
```

When I try to remove to object I got error removing a detached instance.

I did sysout's before and after the merge, both are false, but I don't know why. Why my object is still detached?

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance kaczynski.impl.Cat#1
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaDeleteEventListener.performDetachedEntityDeletionCheck(JpaDeleteEventListener.java:69)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:106)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:73)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:920)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:896)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.remove(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.remove(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.remove(Unknown Source)
>       at kaczynski.DBaccess.AnimalDAO.deleteById(AnimalDAO.java:88)
>       at kaczynski.DBaccess.AnimalDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5f2786e9.invoke()
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
>       at kaczynski.DBaccess.AnimalDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$53a0549d.deleteById()
>       at kaczynski.web.AnimalsController.dropAnimal(AnimalsController.java:48)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

before stackTrace i have this message:

> kwi 21, 2016 10:47:45 AM        org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>       SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with     path [/zapisywacz.baza] threw exception [Request processing failed;     nested exception is     org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Removing a     detached instance kaczynski.impl.Cat#1; nested exception is     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance     kaczynski.impl.Cat#1] with root cause

and this is the output of hascodes:

```
false
1870474474
after merge
445252736
false
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="myDatabase" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="tutorial" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mojaBaza" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect " />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Animal Entity

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Animal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private int age;
    @Column(name="date_of_birth")
    private String dateOfBirth;

    private double weight;

    public Animal(String name, int age, String dateOfBirth, double weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public Animal() {}

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " id= " + id + " name=" + name + ", age=" + age
                + ", dateOfBirth=" + dateOfBirth + ", weight=" + weight;
    }

    public String tease() {
        return "";
    }

    public String giveVoice() {
        return "";
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: why not just create a `query` that does the delete directly?

Comment: post the error stacktrace

Comment: @Scary Wombat i know i can do this , but its just to learn things, not necessarily the most efficient way, hope you understand :)

Comment: why do you try to merge?

Comment: Does your DAO run in a transactional context? If not that's probably the problem, i.e. the jpa session is destroyed right after accessing the entity manager, detaching the entities in the process.

Comment: As said by @Abdelhak, please post the stacktrace associated. Addicionaly, do you mind adding the following to your code `System.out.println(entity.hashCode());`, both before and after the `entity = entityManager.merge(entity);`, please

Comment: @JoãoRebelo have a look at the stacktrace at the bottom, that's what Abdelhak asked for.

Comment: @Thomas how can i check if my DAO runs in such context?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with spring but I'd start looking for `@Transactional` etc.

Comment: @filemonczyk do you mind posting your persistence.xml also, please? Or comment if you have JTA transaction enabled? `    <persistence-unit name="xpto" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>xpto</jta-data-source>`

Comment: Another thing you may try out is at the method head before `TypedQuery<Animal> query...`: `entityManager.getTransaction().begin()`and after `entityManager.remove(entity);` call `entityManager.getTransaction.commit();`

Comment: methods are with @Transactional , persistence is up there

Comment: @filemonczyk, please try adding the code I have asked on my last comment. And see if it works. If it does I will submit an answer accordingly!

Comment: Can you post the Animal entity ?

Comment: Animal entity up, @João Rebelo the solution with entityManager wont work because its like calling another em inside of previous em, nevertheless iI've tried it and it gives error

Comment: Are you following any tutorial? If so, can you link it? From the looks of your `persistence.xml` you're declaring your transactions as local (`transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"`) and not managed by the container which should allow you to programmatically determine the transactionality of your method calls. That error shouldn't occur. From the stacktrace you're also using tomcat as the container for your application which as I am aware of isn't itself a JPA container.

Comment: its not a tutorial, its my own monster that i have created :D

Comment: Do you mind trying another thing? On your persistence.xml change the value of `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"` to `transaction-type="JTA"`, recompile, and see what happens! :)

Comment: same errror , detached

Comment: maybe i have something wrong with imports?

package kaczynski.DBaccess;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;


import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import javax.sql.DataSource;



import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


import kaczynski.impl.Animal;

Comment: @filemonczyk please, have a look at this link on [how to setup Spring JPA](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/12/13/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-3-1-and-jpa/). I believe that something is wrong and you are missing your transacional provider, even though it gives you error when you programatically try to manage the transactions. Also, instead of using the `@PersistentContext` annotation, try it with `@PersistenceUnit(name="myDatabase")` on your entityManager.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109811/discussion-between-joao-rebelo-and-filemonczyk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution,

in spring config  is missing, and because of that annotation @Transactional, was not visible to spring.

Answer (score 0):

After merge, the object detached from session and for remove it you have to find it again.

```
TypedQuery<Animal> query = entityManager.createQuery("Select e from Animal e where e.id="+id, Animal.class);
Animal entity = query.getSingleResult();
entityManager.remove(entity);
```